# How to get back original value from Any in Swift?

Tags: swift

I encountered a serious problem. This is in understandable with my knowledge.

```
    let a1:Int?     =   11223344
    let a2:Any      =   a1
    let a3:Int?     =   a2 as? Int

    println(a3)

    // result: nil
```

Why does this happen with `Any`? How can I get back the original value from `Any`?

I am using Xcode 6.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `a1` to be an `Optional`, which is a type of `enum`, and then assign the Optional (enum) value to `a2`. Note that an enum is not an `Int`, so your attempt to dynamically cast `a2` to `Int` using `as?` fails. As a result, `a3` is set to `nil`.

To fix this, you can explicitly unwrap the optional value, like so:

```
    let a2:Any =  a1!
```

Comment: You could also achieve the same result by declaring a2 to be Optional<Any>.